# TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, base64

1) I am trying to decode a GET request something like this **abb197313b83ad9f16a946c8be35a0f8** but I am getting this error.

*TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object.*

```
let decoder;

    const parseMetadataString = (metadata_string) => {
    const kv_pair_list = metadata_string.split(',');

    return kv_pair_list.reduce((metadata, kv_pair) => {
        const [key, base64_value] = kv_pair.split(' ');

        metadata[key] = {
            encoded: base64_value,
            decoded: Buffer.from(base64_value, 'base64').toString('ascii'),
        };
        return decoder = metadata;
    }, {});
}

  app.get('/upload/files/:fileid', (req, res) => {
   const { fileid } = req.params;
   parseMetadataString(fileid);
   res.sendFile(__dirname + /files/ + decoder);
  });
```

2) If I do it this way I get this error:

*TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined*

But it does res.sendFile with the correct name.

```
let decoder;

  const parseMetadataString = (metadata_string) => {
    const kv_pair_list = metadata_string.split(',');

    return kv_pair_list.reduce((metadata, kv_pair) => {
        const [key, base64_value] = kv_pair.split(' ');

        metadata[key] = {
            encoded: base64_value,
            decoded: Buffer.from(base64_value, 'base64').toString('ascii'),
        };
        return decoder = metadata;
    }, {});
}

  app.get('/upload/files/:fileid', (req, res) => {
   const { fileid } = req.params;
   res.sendFile(__dirname + /files/ + decoder.name.decoded);
});

 server.on(EVENTS.EVENT_UPLOAD_COMPLETE, (event) => {
   parseMetadataString(event.file.upload_metadata);
 });
```

Comment: you shoul write req.params.fileid

Comment: @Akshaypadwal 
const { fileid } = req.params; 
it is already there.

Comment: It seems to be an error from `Buffer.from`, check out your `base64_value` if it may be `undefined` or not.

Comment: Also, your `decoder` seems to be an object with type `{ [key: string]: { decoded: string, encoded: string } }`. Is your response file name correct? I think the response file will be `<your code folder>/files/[object Object]`

Comment: @momocow kindly check my updated post

Comment: anyone please??

Comment: Any example of what `event.file.upload_metadata` contains?

Comment: @momocow file is an object. upload_metadata is a property which contains  this " name cGV4ZWxzLXBob3RvLmpwZw==,type aW1hZ2UvanBlZw== "

Comment: There is a problem in your code. `decoder` is assigned in `parseMetadataString` which is called when server received `EVENT_UPLOAD_COMPLETE` event but consumed when a HTTP GET request is received for path `/upload/files/:fileid`. You have to ensure that `EVENT_UPLOAD_COMPLETE` event happens before any HTTP GET request for the specified path arrives, or `decoder` will be undefined.

Comment: You really just need to add some log statements because you aren't getting the values you expect to get. In your first example, `metadata_string` being `""` would result in your error because key would be `""` and base64_value would be `undefined`. In your second example, like the other comment says, your decoder is undefined. Why is it declared in the module scope anyway? You could just `return metadata` from your reduce function. Declaring it in module scope may be leading to race conditions too. If a req comes in without fieldid it will erase it from decoder - which may be your problem.